# Questions about answer to -> $f:X\to Y$ ($X$ and $Y$ metric spaces) Show that $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$ if $E$ is a dense subset of the metric space X

Tags: real-analysis

I understand the below is a given solution but have some questions about why that is.

Let $f(x)\in f(X)$ and given $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $d_Y(f(x),f(p))<\varepsilon$ for all $p\in X$ with $d_X(x,p)<\delta$. Since $E$ is dense in $X$, there is a point $p_0\in E$ such that $d_X(x,p_0)<\delta$. It follows that $d_Y(f(x),f(p_0))<\varepsilon$, and we conclude that either $f(x)=f(p_0)$ or  $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(E)$ (since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary). Hence $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$.

a) Why exactly does the "$d_X(x,p_0)<\delta$. It follows that $d_Y(f(x),f(p_0))<\varepsilon$" part imply that $f(x)=f(p_0)$ or  $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(E)$? I think I get the part where it could be a limit point, since by definition ANY neighborhood around $f(x)$ has an $f(p_0)$ due to the arbitrarily small (or large) "distance" given by $\varepsilon$, but I don't understand the equality part. Is it just because the distance between them is ANY distance smaller than $\varepsilon$ and so inclusive of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of the solution is poorly worded.  It could have ended as “It follows that $d_Y(f(x),f(p_0))<\varepsilon$, we have shown that a ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $f(x)$ intersects $f(E)$. Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$.”

And in fact, what the solution says is not exactly right logic. Sure $f(x)$ *could* be identical to $f(p_0)$ since it is one of the points in the ε ball, but having made the point $p_0$ dependent on ε, it’s incomplete to claim at this point (while still discussing a ball dependent on epsilon )that either the points are identical or $f(x)$  is a limit point of $f(E)$.

Comment: Can you explain why exactly it would be incomplete to claim that last part? If it's a member of the ball then (by the earlier part of the proof) it must be either a limit point (inside the ball) or $f(x)$ itself shouldn't it?

Comment: Basically, just what I said in the second paragraph.  $p_0$ is a point dependent on ε. So, at the point in the argument, it is not okay to say something that is independent of ε, namely that f(x) is a limit point (this is mixed up with another possibility that IS dependent on epsilon, namely that f(x)=f(p0). ). To know your logic is right, first you finish saying what can be concluded given ε.  Only then you can say use the arbitrariness of ε to draw a conclusion such as that f(x) is a limit point.

Answer (score 1):

It just complicates the proof. There is no need for it, since what you did proves correctly that every ball centered at $f(x)$ contains an element of the image of $E$. Therefore, $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$.